# How to make QDockWidget to expand when the window is resized?

Tags: qt, qt4, qdockwidget

I have a simple form: `QDockWidget` on the right side, `QGroupBox` on the left side of `QMainWindow`. `QGroupBox` is layed out using vertical layout.

I want `QDockWidget` to be expanded and occupy all the free space when the main window is enlarged or maximized.

How do I do it?

Bellow is the source code of my *.ui* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>653</width>
    <height>381</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QDockWidget" name="dockWidget">
   <attribute name="dockWidgetArea">
    <number>2</number>
   </attribute>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents"/>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to reimplement [QWidget::changeEvent](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#changeEvent) (or a `resizeEvent` for resizing) to react to `QEvent::WindowStateChange`. If one of those events occurs, get the [QWidget::windowState](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowState) and resize your dock to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I resize the dock widget? `resize ( int, int )` doesn't help. Resizing of dockWidgetContents also doesn't help.